# JSON parsing only one branch of whole message java using GsonBuilder and InputStream Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I just try to integrate with external webservice via JSON from Android. I receive following JSON format:

[image]

Data that i'm interested in is in "messages" branch.
To access data i'm using :

```
builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY);
Gson gson = builder.create();
ClassToStore response = gson.fromJson(reader, ClassToStore.class);
```

where reader is a input stream from:

```
am = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets();
am.open("data.json");
```

Message structure looks like:

[image]

ClassToStore has all fields with the same names.

I get all objects but all of theme are null's

PLEASE HELP :(

My classToStore:

public static class ClassToStore implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1463052486583654136L;

```
public String id ;
public String replied_to_id ;
public String sender_id ;
public String created_at ;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getReplied_to_id() {
    return replied_to_id;
}

public String getSender_id() {
    return sender_id;
}

public String getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the `ClassToStore` code.

Comment: look above, just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an extra class to match the outer object:

```
public class OuterObject {
    List<ClassToStore> messages;    
}
```

And then load it like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<OuterObject>>(){}.getType();
List<OuterObject> outerList = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
List<ClassToStore> listOfMessages = outerlist.get(0).messages;
```